# CreateTextNode in javascript appends html content

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to append html formatted block to a existing div using append child. But I see the html code is appending instead of formatted html. Any pointer on how to add html design instead of html code with appendChild and createTextNode?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdv6yqcL/2/)

```
<div id="currentElement">
  <div>
    <h2>
    Hello test
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
var ele = document.getElementById("currentElement");
var newHtml = "<div><h3>hello test continued</h3></div>";
ele.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newHtml));
```

Comment: yes, because a text node is text, not HTML. `ele.innerHTML += newHTML` or, a better alternative `ele.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml)` is what you want https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use **[`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**? You can use `ele.innerHTML = newHtml` to overwrite the content, or `ele.innerHTML += newHtml` to add to the existing content.

```js
var ele = document.getElementById("currentElement");
var newHtml = "<div><h3>hello test continued</h3></div>";
ele.innerHTML += newHtml;
```

```html
<div id="currentElement">
  <div>
    <h2>
      Hello test
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that this will remove any existing event handlers. In order to retain handlers, you should use **[`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)** instead:

```js
var ele = document.getElementById("currentElement");
var newHtml = "<div><h3>hello test continued</h3></div>";
ele.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);
```

```html
<div id="currentElement">
  <div>
    <h2>
      Hello test
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that `.insertAdjacentHTML()` provides the ability to choose *where* the inserted text should go with one of the following as the (mandatory) first function parameter:

- `beforebegin`: Before the element itself.
- `afterbegin`: Just inside the element, before its first child.
- `beforeend`: Just inside the element, after its last child.
- `afterend`: After the element itself.

I've gone with `beforeend` in the above example.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: that would REPLACE the current html :p (comment pre edit) (and if you want to ADD it, `insertAdjacentHTML` is more performant :p)

Comment: @JaromandaX -- Updated to cover both replacement and addition :)

Comment: this will remove existing event listeners.  any option with appendChild?

Comment: insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 1):

If you want do it by appendChild, do it this way :

```
var newHtml = "<div><h3>hello test continued</h3></div>";
var child = document.createElement('div');
child.innerHTML = newHtml;
child = child.firstChild;
document.getElementById('currentElement').appendChild(child);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vdv6yqcL/10/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve event listeners, you have two options

```js
// sample event listener
document.querySelector('#currentElement h2').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('click works'));
// code starts here
var ele = document.getElementById("currentElement");
var div = document.createElement('div'), 
    h3 = document.createElement('h3'),
    txt = document.createTextNode('hello test continued');
div.appendChild(h3);
h3.appendChild(txt);
ele.appendChild(div);
```

```html
<div id="currentElement">
  <div>
    <h2>
    Hello test
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```js
// sample event listener
document.querySelector('#currentElement h2').addEventListener('click', () => console.log('click works'));
// code starts here
var ele = document.getElementById("currentElement");
var newHtml = "<div><h3>hello test continued</h3></div>";
ele.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);
```

```html
<div id="currentElement">
  <div>
    <h2>
    Hello test
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```